# getting mounted drive accesable by user

Tags: fstab

so I have 2 external drives on a ubuntu computer, and the mount point in fstab is in my home directory. however, I seems to only be writable by root. heres the relevent fstab lines:

```
/dev/sdb1  /home/henry/usb3hdd0  ext4  user,nosuid,uhelper=udisks,noexec,nodev  0       2
/dev/sdc1  /home/henry/usb2hdd1  ext4  user,nosuid,uhelper=udisks,noexec,nodev  0       2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `chown -R /home/henry/usb3hdd0 /home/henry/usb2/hdd1` to give you access to all the files on the disk.  Ownership will follow wherever you mount the disk.  Default owner for the root directory of a disk.  You need to change it to allow you access.

I was thinking windows partitions in which case you would have various options.

- Add `noauto` to the options, and mount it yourself.  I believe this will give you access.
- Add `user=henry` to the options.  This will give you access to disks.
- Add the appropriate mode option to enable access.